# STM32F407ZET6 could not verify ST device

Tags: stm32, openocd, gdb, stmcubeide

I have a setup where I bought a STM32F407ZET6 dev board from AliExpress and have been using for almost 6 years using STM32Cube IDE. It was only until i updated my IDE from 1.6 to 1.14 when it started saying that "Could not verify ST Device! Please verify that the latest version of gdb-server is used for the connection". my openocd is remotely running on Raspberry pi where it uses the bitbanging driver to drive the GPIOs for establishing an SWD connection.

This same question has been addressed in several other threads in the context of bluepill (https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-boards-and-hardware/how-to-deal-wirh-could-not-verify-st-device/td-p/234230/page/2).

On the OpenOCD side, i am getting this error:

[image]

I tried changing the -expected-id $_CPUTAPID to different values suggested in different posts (including 0), but nothing works. Most of the forums talk about this issue in the context of Bluepill; however this is STM32F407 based board.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: The link to ST community thread shows the issue is in ST-Link not being authentic ST device, the ST tools (CubeIDE, etc) are actively resisting cloned devices for quite some time now. Are you using the cheap clone of ST-Link?

Comment: I am not using any ST Link at all. I am using Rapberry pi's gpio bit banged by OpenOCD to immitate SWD protocol.